# Xcode error will not let me tap sign up or login

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface

I am fairly new to Xcode and Swift and I have encountered an error that I can not debug for the life of me. When I launch the app, I cannot tap my login or sign up button without getting a "Thread 1: Exception" error. Please help!

Here is my code for my ViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var videoPlayer:AVPlayer?

    var videoPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer?

    @IBOutlet weak var LoginButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var SignUpButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setUpElements()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Set up video in the background
        setUpVideo()
    }

    func setUpElements() {

        Utilities.styleFilledButton(SignUpButton)
        Utilities.styleHollowButton(LoginButton)

    }

    func setUpVideo() {

        // Get the path to the resource in the bundle
        let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "grass", ofType: "mp4")

        guard bundlePath != nil else {
            return
        }

        // Create a URL from it
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)

        // Create the video player item
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

        // Create the player
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

        // Create the layer
        videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer!)

        // Adjust the size and frame
        videoPlayerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x:
            -self.view.frame.size.width*1.5, y: 0, width:
            self.view.frame.size.width*4, height:
            self.view.frame.size.height)

        view.layer.insertSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!, at: 0)

        // Add it to the view and play it
        videoPlayer?.playImmediately(atRate: 1)

    }
    @IBAction func LoginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func SignUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

And the error I am receiving is "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" when I hit the login button, and then a Thread 1:signal SIGABART on line 14 of my AppDelegate next to class APPDelegate: UIResponder, UIAPPlicationDelegate.

The code on my AppDelegate is below.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        FirebaseApp.configure()


        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post screenshots of your code, but copy paste them in your question. See also [ask].  And please add the code for your ViewController.

Comment: Okay! Is that better?

Comment: Your function is called `LoginTapped`, but from your error message (in the screenshot) it said `loginTapped`. So I think there's your problem.

Comment: By Swift naming convention functions and properties should be `lowerCamelCase`. See also https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming

Comment: Awesome thanks I found my mistype! It was a lowercase letter... beginner errors holding me back!

Comment: What are your Utility functions doing (styleFilledButton and styleHollowButton)? Is there any more error message output you can post?